# java software quality in eclipse while developing

Tags: java, performance, quality-center, web, qa-architect

How can I increase the quality of code while developing itself. Is there nay tool available which will analyse my code and tell which part of code will create performance issue. I dont want different graphs and statistics. I nee straightforward result.

Answer (score 3):

You asked about quality, but then you asked about performance, so I assume you are specifically interested in performance.  The short answer is no.   There are tools that will analyze performance while it is running to tell you which parts of the code are the busiest.  Those tools will not tell you whether you are using slow algorithms.  And a hot spot is not necessarily inefficient.